# What's the difference between Nakamoto consensus vs Proof-of-Authority vs BFT

Tags: parity, proof-of-stake, consensus, proof-of-work, proof-of-authority

Documentations all around the internet are filled with these terms to categorise consensus protocols. What is the difference between them.

For example: many call parity's tendermint as a BFT type whereas official docs say it's a PoA protocol.

Can we have proper definition to them and also what are the other categories?